# How to self teach math? (when you have other academic commitments)

Tags: education

I'm an physics undergrad student. I find my math course curricula irrelevant and my teachers unable to teach us in a way to build up a minimum back ground to further study in the field of physics and mathematical sciences. In order to do well in the exams, it is enough to solve problems from previous years and that's basically a lot memorizing and all that stuff.

I want to be self educated in mathematics using textbooks. But I find it difficult to go through the whole textbook while keeping up with the academic curriculum. For instance, I have a course in Mathematical Physics. I wanted to work through the whole book of Mathematical Methods by Arfken. I felt that if I just rush through the exercises then I will be missing out on the insights that I must gather. On the other hand if I be too "slow" and think too much then I won't be able to cover the materials for my exams.

How can I figure out which problems to do and how much time should I spend on them??

Comment: does the book has any starred problems that indicate toughness

Comment: Yep you are quite right, a lot of people don't manage to do both their duties and their learning/research as well as they would want to (within working hours). So it's not only you.

Comment: There are no such starred problems. The author actually wrote that do as many problems as you can. That's why I'm a bit lost. Can't figure out what to do and when to stop

Comment: My two cents:  I'd error on the side of deep study (within reason, of course,), over moving through speedily in a rather shallow study of the book(s).  In the long run, the deep study will stick with you far better than just skimming (or going to quickly) through the texts you have.